# preg_match a string with repeated data in it

Tags: php, string, preg-match

For example i have next string :

```
2556974513|0123254852|1025635214|1236521025|0124576832
```

in the string must be `10` digits then `|` and this formula may be repeated `n` times, how to match it?

maybe there is an easiest way to do that, than this :

```
preg_match('/^[\d]{10}|[\d]{10}| ... [\d]{10}$/', $string);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want something like this:

```
^(?:\d{10}\|)+\d{10}$
```

The `\d{10}` at the end is there since there is no `|` character at the end.  The `+` will match one or more of the preceding pattern.  If it is valid to match only one group of 10 digits then replace the `+` with `*` which will match zero or more times.

Note that the `|` character needs to be escaped, because it is used as an OR operator in regex.

Comment: thanks but the number of repetitions is dynamic,in this case I have to explode the string then count number of the repetition every time. Is there a way where preg_match calculates by itself number of the repetitions?

Comment: @John: ^(?:\d{10}\|)*\d{10}$ – you may want to read up about regular expressions, the question you asked is pretty simple.

Comment: @John - Ahh I misunderstood the question, edited my answer so that it will match any number of repetitions.  If it is valid to have a single group of 10 digits (ie '2556974513' should match), then replace the `+` in the regex with `*` which will match 0 or more times.

Comment: @GaretJax, i know... sometimes the easiest code may get you in troubles :) ( I'm writing the code from morning untill now, i'm a bit tired, so i just forget about ), thanks

Comment: I think your + should be * -- i.e., the case where you have just a single value and no pipes. (If that's even possible in the OP's case... <shrug>)

Answer (score 1):

This means "one or more of (10 digits then pipe)":

```
(\d{10}\|)+
```

Edit: It's not clear from your question if the tailing pipe will be there or not. If not, then:

```
(\d{10}\|)*(\d{10})
```

Also, if you need to extract the values anyway, you may as well just do:

```
foreach (explode('|', $string) as $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $value)) {
        ...
    }
}
```